# Unity 3D UI Buttons not working on mobile device

Tags: android, button, unity-game-engine

For few days I'm encountering a strange problem that my buttons don't work when I build and run my game on the mobile device even though they work just fine in the editor. What's even more surprising is only the buttons that are placed for the actual gameplay level don't work. All buttons prior to that level on the menu screens and work.

This problem only started occurring a couple of days ago before that there was no such thing. I worked around this problem by first building the game with Orientation 'Landscape Left' and then again building it with 'Auto Rotation' and checking the 'Landscape Left' checkbox in the player settings or vice versa. That will make buttons work again on the mobile device. But today when I build a second level I found that this problem also occur on Second level even though I made it to work on first level.

It's driving me crazy, I don't know what to do. The only difference between Menu and gameplay level is that on the gameplay level I'm placing objects using some objects using Instantiate.

Yes, I have checked I have placed the EventSYstem on the level and GraphicsRaycaster script on the canvas.
Any ideas?

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose here, could you expand your question to include sample code and/or screenshots for the Hierarchy & Inspector. Ensure you set the Canvas render mode to `Screen Space - Camera`

Comment: in a project, my UI buttons worked in Editor but not worked in Android device. my problem was solved after searching on "problems with IsPointerOverGameObject()" function.
the bellow page helped me to solve this problem. I hope it is usefull for you. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1115464/ispointerovergameobject-not-working-with-touch-inp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found the problem. I was using a canvas within a canvas and both has raycasting script applied to it. Removing the ray casting script from the child canvas appears to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone, I ran into a similar issue. I was implementing a tabbed UI by using a parent transform representing each tab (so I could easily activate/deactivate by tab). Any buttons that were not an immediate child of the canvas (e.g. one under a tab) were not clickable when running on Android.